# How to inject PHP code with $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Tags: php, inject

On server side I have code:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ' ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ' still alive';
```

How cat I use it to inject shell? There no DB on a server.

Trying set Host header in request, and it show on client, but only showig :(

Comment: This sounds a little dodgy...

Comment: That's ok, I testing my code on penetration.
And study new vulnerabilities techniture.